# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected the_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (14174, 1)

Tags: lstm, rnn, speech-to-text, reshape

hope you're all doing good !

I am working on Automatic Speech Recognition with Python with the LibriSpeech Dataset.
After preprocessing the audios data and applying an "MFCC featurizing" I append everything into a list and get a shape of `(14174,)`. Knowing that each sample has a different length but the same number of features for example :

```
print(X[0].shape)
print(X[12000].shape)
>> (615, 13)
>> (301, 13)
```

Now when I feed the data into my network with an Input layer defined as

```
input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=(None, input_dim)) # with input_dim = 13 MFCC features
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected the_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (14174, 1)
```

I tried reshaping with different shapes but I am still struggling.

This is the model

```
def final_model(input_dim, units, output_dim=29):
    """ Build a bidirectional recurrent network for speech
    """
    # Main acoustic input
    input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=(None, input_dim))
    
    # =============== 1st Layer =============== #
    # Add bidirectional recurrent layer
    bidirectional_rnn = Bidirectional(GRU(units, activation=None,return_sequences=True, implementation=2, name='bidir_rnn'))(input_data)
    # Add batch normalization
    batch_normalization = BatchNormalization(name = "batch_normalization_bidirectional_rnn")(bidirectional_rnn)
    # Add activation function
    activation = Activation('relu')(batch_normalization)
    # Add dropout
    #drop = Dropout(rate = 0.1)(activation)
    
    # =============== 2nd Layer =============== #
    # Add bidirectional recurrent layer
    bidirectional_rnn = Bidirectional(GRU(units, activation=None,return_sequences=True, implementation=2, name='bidir_rnn'))(activation)
    # Add batch normalization
    batch_normalization = BatchNormalization(name = "bn_bidir_rnn_2")(bidirectional_rnn)
    # Add activation function
    activation = Activation('relu')(batch_normalization)
    # Add dropout
    #drop = Dropout(rate = 0.1)(activation)
    
    # =============== 3rd Layer =============== #
    # Add a TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim)) layer
    time_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim))(activation)
    # Add softmax activation layer
    y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(time_dense)
    
    # Specify the model
    model = Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=y_pred)
    model.output_length = lambda x: x
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code where you feed the data to your network.

Comment: @AdamOudad
`model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`
`model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.3, epochs=3)`
I am new to Time Series Prediction so I am still struggling to code a generator Class...

Comment: I see no problem in this code either. This has probably to do with the definition of your model. Please show how you define your model also. You should edit your question and give a reproducible code, so that people can help you! :)

Comment: @AdamOudad Oh Thanks ! I added the code of the model on the text.

Comment: If this is keras then keras requires same number of timesteps within a single batch. You can try padding and masking

Comment: @skrrrt I applied a padding on the inputs and the outputs now I got the following shapes but a new error came up `((214, 1719, 13), (214, 288))` **`expected softmax to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (214, 288)`**

Comment: I don't think you were supposed to add padding to the outputs

Comment: @skrrrt Actually it is helpful I solved the issue above but now am having an issue with the ctc function...

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs have different length so as suggested by @skrrrt, you should pad your data and apply a mask into your model.

The following pads all your input with `0.` values so that all sequences have the same length.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
padded_inputs = pad_sequences(X, padding="post", dtype='float')
```

You can choose which value to use for padding with the parameter `value=0.0` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences))

Then, add a masking layer just after your input layer in your model.

```
    # Main acoustic input
    input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=(None, input_dim))
    masked_input = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(input_data)
    bidirectional_rnn = Bidirectional(GRU(units, activation=None,return_sequences=True, implementation=2, name='bidir_rnn'))(masked_input)
```

[Refer to this tutorial for more information](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding).